# How to get all Google Map direction result points

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

I know that I can find points using response.routes[0].overview_path but for longer distance route not all points included in this collection.

Is any other way how I can get ALL points?

Comment: Process through all the legs of the route retrieving the points.  [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to geocodezip!

The solution is to process through all legs and steps.

```c#
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendOptions);
var result = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

var route = result.routes[0];
var points = new Array();
var legs = route.legs;
for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            points.push(nextSegment[k]);
        }
    }
}
```